# « hors-service » ou « hors service »

Tags: orthographe

En me documentant un peu, j'ai pu trouver sur [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Emploi_du_trait_d%27union_pour_les_pr%C3%A9fixes_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Adverbes_non,_hors,_tr%C3%A8s_et_quasi) que pour les adverbes `non`, `hors`, `très` et `quasi`, la règle suivante s'appliquait :

> Si le mot suivant est un nom ou un verbe substantivé (à
>   l'infinitif), alors on utilise le trait d'union après l'adverbe, par
>   exemple hors-gel, hors-service.

On peut remarquer cette façon d'écrire sur plusieurs sites (p. ex. [Wikitionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hors-service), [Reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/hors-service), [Le Dictionnaire](https://www.le-dictionnaire.com/definition/hors-service), etc.).

Toutefois, d'[autres sources](https://www.logilangue.com/public/Site/clicGrammaire/Hors-Trait.htm) mentionnent une règle différente :

> On lie le mot « hors » par un trait d'union au nom qui le suit quand les
>   deux mots forment un nom. Dans tous les autres cas, le mot
>   « hors » n'est pas lié par un trait d'union.

Cette dernière règle semble être suivie par [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/service/72393/locution?q=hors%20service#184033) qui l'écrit sans trait d'union.

Est-ce que les deux manières de l'écrire sont acceptées ? Sinon, laquelle des deux règles est fausse ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selon le [dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9H0963), l’orthographe correcte est sans le trait d'union :

> Hors sert à former un certain nombre de locutions dans lesquelles il
>   signifie En dehors de (au sens propre et au sens figuré). Prendre ses
>   vacances hors saison. Des propos tenus hors séance. Un morceau de
>   musique hors programme, joué en supplément de programme. Une question
>   d’examen hors programme. Un devoir hors sujet. **Un appareil hors
>   service**, qui ne fonctionne plus, qui est en panne.

Il y a l'air d'y avoir cependant quelques exceptions, comme par exemple [hors-texte](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9H0972) ou [hors-piste](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9H0970), quand ils sont utilisés comme substantifs au lieu d'adjectifs (auquel cas il n'y a pas de trait d'union).

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette réponse. J'ai modifié la page Wikitionnaire et Wikipédia dans ce sens.